# X11 | multiplier & maxDiff number to multiple the shares by in order to display hashrate

Tags: x11, hashpower

What is the correct formula for X11 to calculate hashrate?

> right maxDiff number to multiple the shares by in order to display
>   hashrate

We need hashrate **multiplier** and the **maxdiff**

Example:

```
scrypt: 2^16

sha256d: 2^32
```

maxDiff with:

`scrypt: 0x0000ffff00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000`, 
`sha256d: 0x00000000ffff0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

diff1 for X11 is

0x00000000ffff0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000